# MySQLでのデータの結合について

Tags: mysql, database

次のようなデータベースがあります。名前が同じもの同士でデータが足りないもの同士を結合して表示するSQL文があれば教えてください
[image: データベースの例とその出力結果]

Comment: 同じ名前で、項目がどちらも埋まっている場合の挙動はどうなる想定でしょうか？

Comment: コメントありがとうございます。項目がどちらも埋まっている場合は存在しません。とあるAPIを叩いてMySQLにデータを入れた結果似たような形になりました。

Answer (score 3):

ポイントは `名前` でグルーピングする事ですね。

同じ列値がない状況であれば、

```
select
    名前
   ,max(住所)
   ,max(電話番号)
from 顧客DB
group by 名前
```

で良いと思います。

もし同じ列値があるのなら、

```
select
    名前
   ,group_concat(住所) as 住所
   ,group_concat(電話番号) as 電話番号
from 顧客DB
group by 名前
```

とすれば、住所や電話番号が `,` 区切りで連結されて出力されます。

Comment: ありがとうございます！解決しました！文字列でMAXを使う発想はありませんでした